# What is the "world" access level in a java program?

Tags: java, oop, public

```
Access Levels
Modifier        Class   Package Subclass    World
public            Y       Y       Y          Y
protected         Y       Y       Y          N
(Default)         Y       Y       N          N
private           Y       N       N          N
```

what is the "World" access level? How is it different from the package access level?

EDIT: MY BAD. Had fallacy that all code in a program is in a single package.

Comment: Uh, public? Public is the most open, and there's pretty much nothing that can't access a public field.

Comment: *World* means *every element*, regardless of its position.

Comment: @oxguy3 i don't get it. how is that different from being able to be accessed from the entire package?

Comment: @qaz Not all Java code lives in the same package.  A package is something like `java.util` or `com.google.common.base` or `org.junit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes directly from the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

Access Levels

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World

public      Y       Y       Y           Y
protected   Y       Y       Y           N
no modifier Y       Y       N           N
private     Y       N       N           N
```

> The first data column indicates whether the class itself has access to
>   the member defined by the access level. As you can see, a class always
>   has access to its own members. The second column indicates whether
>   classes in the same package as the class (regardless of their
>   parentage) have access to the member. The third column indicates
>   whether subclasses of the class declared outside this package have
>   access to the member. The fourth column indicates whether all classes
>   have access to the member.

The scope of "world" is literally "everything" -- any class, *regardless of the package to which it belongs*, can access a class declared with the `public` access modifier.

Contrast this with `protected`, which means that classes within the package and subclasses of the protected class regardless of package can access the class.

Answer (score 1):

public is the most wider access level in java.There's no restriction on either accessing attributes or inheriting the class members.They are visible in all package.So,eventually there's nothing like world modifier rather it might be just a synonym to define public.